# Exchange/outlook: default from address for a mailbox with multiple addresses

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

We have a shared exchange mailbox with multiple SMTP addresses; foo@company.com, bar@company.com, baz@company.com and so on.

When a user replies to a mail in this mailbox we want the from: field to default to the address the original mail was sent to; so if a mail was sent to bar@company.com the reply should come from bar@company.com and not the default foo@company.com.

Users can change the from: address manually per email, but that is leading to mistakes as they leave it on the default value.

Is there any way to change the default from behaviour in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate mailboxes are the way forward I'm afraid, there's no native functionality in Outlook to allow the picking of a secondary SMTP address over the primary or another secondary.

Comment: Well, there is the one way, natively.  Seems that OP's users keep mis-clicking when using that native function, however.

Comment: Hopeless N00b is exactly right, that why I want to automate it if possible.